# Fragment Shader for sampling 3 components gradient vs one RGB

Tags: opengl, shader, textures, sampling

I want to sample gradient with three components separated as opposed to one combined gradient

I tried :

```
 out.x = texture2D(inputTexture, vec2(color.x, 0)).x ;
 out.y = texture2D(inputTexture, vec2(color.y, 1)).y ;
 out.z = texture2D(inputTexture, vec2(color.z, 2)).z ;
```

But it outputs messed up colours with a lot of noise.

This the three component gradient with 3 pixel height :

These are the images after I applied

```
out.x = texture2D(inputTexture, vec2(color.x, 0.0)).x ;
out.y = texture2D(inputTexture, vec2(color.y, 0.5)).y ;
out.z = texture2D(inputTexture, vec2(color.z, 0.9)).z ;
```

[image] => [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texture coordinates are stored in the range of 0-1, NOT in texel space, so when you are asking for a pixel with a y coord of 2, you are asking for something off the texture, and the result you get back will be dependant on whether nor not you are clamping or wrapping the texture.

Try asking for the y coords of 0.0, 0.5 and 0.9

A better solution might be to use a texture with a single gradient, and sample the channels from that individually. The following texture and code will give the same result:

[image: RampTexture]

```
out.x = texture2D(inputTexture, vec2(color.x, 0)).x ;
out.y = texture2D(inputTexture, vec2(color.y, 0)).y ;
out.z = texture2D(inputTexture, vec2(color.z, 0)).z ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response I already use the code you mentioned in one pixel gradients and it works fine, but the problem is that when I combine 3 pixel into one the result is not what is expected, so I tried 0.0 , 0.5 and 0.9 for x , y and z respectively but the result is the same noisy with a dark magenta tint. I'm going to add two sample images to the original question.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use multiple gradients instead of one?

Comment: I work with graphist they some times give me these maps and also if I find a way to access other lines of gradients in a texture, I can also load multiple gradients as one texture and refer to different y coordinates as oppose to loading one texture for each gradient.

Comment: Is the texture being filtered at all? It should be set up for point filtering (GL_NEAREST)

Comment: it was GL_LINEAR and change them to     'code'    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); but still there is no difference!

Comment: What might help is sampling the texture in texel space. To do this, you need to convert your coordinates from view space.

To sample to first pixel in the y axis, use the following code

out.x = texture2D(inputTexture, vec2(color.x, 1 /resolution.y)).x ;

You will need to supply a resolution uniform to your shader for this

uniform vec2 resolution;

It should be noted that this will give pretty much the same result as 0.0, 0.5 and 0.9 (they were just precomputed values)

Comment: I added that uniform and still no luck! Thank you for your tries.

Comment: after your suggestions I realized there must be some problem with my code and the way I load my texture, but was involved some where else, so today dug dipper in my code and found the problem, so what you mentioned originally was right to use 0.0 , 0.5 and 0.9 thank you.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad we figured it out :)